# what does $\sum_{m+n=k}f(m,n)$ mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What is $\sum_{m+n=k}f(m,n)$$ and $$\sum_{m+n\leq k}f(m,n)$?

For example :

$$\sum_{m+n=k}\frac{1}{mn}$$ and $$\sum_{m+n\leq k}\frac{1}{mn}.$$

How does one deal with something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have $\displaystyle \sum_{m+n=k} \frac{1}{mn}$, this means to first build the set $\displaystyle S = \left\{ \frac{1}{mn} \ \ \Big| \ m, n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } m + n = k \right\}$ and then add together all the members of $S$.

Likewise, to compute $\displaystyle \sum_{m+n \leq k} \frac{1}{mn}$, we add together all the members of the set $\displaystyle \left\{ \frac{1}{mn} \ \ \Big| \ m, n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } m + n \leq k \right\}$.  In both cases, $k$ is typically a positive integer.

---

For example, in the first scenario, if we have $k = 4$, then there are $3$ possible pairs $(m,n)$ such that $m+n = k$: $(1,3), (2,2), \text{ and } (3,1)$, so we have $\displaystyle \sum_{n+m = 4} \frac{1}{mn} = \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 1}$.

If the condition is instead $m+n \leq 4$, then there are $6$ possible pairs $(m,n)$ that work: $(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), \text{ and } (3,1),$ so we'll have:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{m+n \leq 4} \frac{1}{mn} = \frac{1}{1 \cdot 1} + \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 1} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 1}$$

Comment: can you give more information by computing the sum step by step

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I'll assume that $k$ is some fixed nonnegative integer, and that $m$ and $n$ range over the nonnegative integers. Then
$$
\sum_{m+n=k} f(m,n) = \sum_{m=0}^{k} f(m,k-m).
$$
Using this, we then have
$$
\sum_{m+n \leq k} f(m,n) = \sum_{j=0}^{k} \left[ \sum_{m+n=j} f(m,n) \right] 
= \sum_{j=0}^{k} \left[ \sum_{m=0}^{j} f(m,j-m) \right].
$$
You can always alter things above if you need to change the sets that $m$ and $n$ range over, say, to the positive integers. This would be necessary for your example, where $f(m,n) = 1/(mn)$.

Comment: The brackets $[$ and $]$ are not really necessary, but I included them to make things easier to follow.

Comment: if i can choose both answer as best answer i will also choose yours, thank you alot.

Comment: @user130806 Not a problem. Thanks. Hope my answer helped. :)

Comment: surrrre it helped :)